# ComboBox.Items.Clear() not working

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've run into an issue and despite trying many workarounds (some rather ludicrous ones, too) I'm still stuck at square one.

Simply, all I want to do is clear the list of items in a `ComboBox`. That's it. I've tried many things - `Items.Clear()`, `Text = String.Empty`, even tried a loop that would gradually remove all items one by one - but nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub btnDeleteCategory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteCategory.Click
    'Clear the contents of the drop-down list with records titles.
    cboxDeleteItem.Items.Clear() ' NOT WORKING!!! NO IDEA WHY!!!
    'Set the table name depending on what category the user has selected from the drop-down list.
    Select Case cboxDeleteCategory.Text
        Case "Books"
            TableName = "tblBooks"
            Exit Select
        Case "CDs"
            TableName = "tblCDs"
            Exit Select
        Case "Movies"
            TableName = "tblMovies"
            Exit Select
        Case "TV Shows"
            TableName = "tblTVShows"
            Exit Select
        Case "Video Games"
            TableName = "tblVideoGames"
            Exit Select
    End Select
    'Connect to the corresponding table.
    ChangeTable()
    'Add all of the titles of the records into the other drop-down list.
    Do Until Incremental = MaxRows
        cboxDeleteItem.Items.Add(DataSet.Tables("Main Database").Rows(Incremental).Item("Title"))
        Incremental = Incremental + 1
    Loop
    'Reset Incremental back to 0.
    Incremental = 0
End Sub
```

The way it works is by having the user select a category from a drop-down list called `cboxDeleteCategory` and when the user presses `btnDeleteCategory`, it should remove everything listed in `cboxDeleteItem`. It should then (eventually) re-populate it with the contents of the table it is now connected to - but that's handled elsewhere in the program; not important.

Comment: Not important you say? Instead it is the source of your problem. How do you fill the combobox? If you use a DataSource then there is no way to use Clear on the items. You should set the DataSource to Nothing

Comment: In the code above is how I add items into the drop-down list. I simply Add them one-by-one.

Comment: Could you not just set the `.DataSource` property with `DataSet.Tables("Main Database")`. Then set the `DisplayMember` to "Title".

Comment: I'll give it a quick go.

Comment: @Bugs OK, so that worked (thanks, looks much nicer) but setting cboxDeleteItems.DataSource = Nothing doesn't work. Need to find a way to remove everything and then reload if the user changes their mind. :/

Comment: Looks like there is an issue elsewhere. I think it's probably linked with `ChangeTable`.

Comment: @Bugs You were right! I just chucked in a DataSet.Clear() and it worked! Thanks! :D